# Mockito mock doesn't work properly

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the following test method:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AccountManagerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private AccountManager accountManager = new AccountManagerImpl(null);

    @Mock
    private AuthStorage authStorage;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    /* REGISTER TESTS */

    @Test
    public void test_whenRegister_withAlreadyExistingEmail_thenDoNotRegister() throws AuthStorageException {
        String email = "foo@bar.com";
        String name = "Foo";
        String password = "123456";
        String password2 = "123456";

        doThrow(new AuthStorageException("Email already in use")).when(authStorage).registerNewUser(Matchers.any());
        assertFalse(accountManager.register(email, name, password, password2));
    }
}
```

that tests the following class method:

```
@Override
    public Boolean register(String email, String name, String password, String password2) {
        if (password.equals(password2)) {
            try {
                String pwd = hashPassword(password);
                User user = new User(email, name, pwd);
                AuthStorage authStorage = new AuthStorageImpl();
                authStorage.registerNewUser(user);
                return true;
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | AuthStorageException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // If passwords don't match
        return false;
    }
```

Supposedly, when calling `registerNewUser` it should thow an exception and then the method would return `false`, but when debugging I see that the exception isn't thrown and the program returns `true`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try drop this ` = new AccountManagerImpl(null);`

Comment: I've already tried that. This can't be done because Mockito can't instanciate an interface and if I do
@InjectMocks
private AccountManagerImpl accountManager
i get the same error

Comment: The answer to your question is found on [this page](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't instantiate the object where mocks are inserted:

```
@InjectMocks
private AccountManager accountManager = new AccountManagerImpl(null);
```

Instead, use this:

```
@InjectMocks
private AccountManager accountManager;
```

Then if you use Mockito runner:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

You shouldn't inject mocks directly:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); //remove this line
}
```

And the last point: there is no point to your mocking because you have a local variable in your **register** method:

```
AuthStorage authStorage = new AuthStorageImpl();
authStorage.registerNewUser(user);
```

Which makes the class use your mocked object.